# Lookup Filter display

Tags: lookup-filter

Hi is it possible to change lookup results ? instead of displaying the id/autonumber I want to display custom field/text(got 50 datasets of text

Answer (score 0):

The "Name" field must remain present, but you can add additional fields. Go to the object's Search Layout section, and edit the Lookup Window settings. In Classic, go to the object you want (e.g. Setup > Customize > Accounts > Search Layouts), and in Lightning you'll find it in the Object Manager. You can read more about it in [Customize Search Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout.htm&type=5). You may have up to 10 fields displayed.